# Read all files from directory Spring batch FileReadingMessageSource

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am using spring batch for my application. Basically, all I have to do is read all XML files from the input directory. When I get all the XML files, each file needs to be converted to root Object. That object I have to split into two objects and print them into CSV file. So, if there are 10 XML files in the input folder, I need to generate CSV with 20 lines. If there are 150, CSV will have 300 lines, etc. I meant to use `FileReadingMessageSource`. It has a queue. But the problem with this is the return type of that queue. It returns File, and what I need is the List of queues. Can I somehow get the entire list of XML files from a directory in my reader?

Answer (score 4):

IMO you don't need to use the `FileReadingMessageSource` (and introduce Spring Integration) in your basic use case.

You can create a reader that returns a `File`, a processor that maps the `File` to your root Object (and split in two objects) and finally a `FlatFileItemWriter` to generate the CSV output.

EDIT: add reader example:

```
@Bean
public ItemReader<File> itemReader() throws IOException {
    List<File> files = Files.walk(Paths.get("/path/to/directory"))
            .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
            .map(Path::toFile)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return new IteratorItemReader<>(files);
}
```

Comment: That is not the solution. I simply want to make a reader that returns a list of files, not just one file.

Comment: Added an example of the reader. If you want a reader that returns the list of all files in a directory at once, then you probably need to use a tasklet and not a chunk oriented step. The idea of chunk processing in Spring Batch is to read items (files in your case) one at a time.

Comment: Thank you - your answer and the reader example led me to https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html and are first hints on how to read image files (*.arw, *.jpg) into a Spring Batch step, although I'm still on my way through https://www.springer.com/de/book/9781484237236 (the ItemReader section doesn't cover "binary" file formats).