# How to use partitioning and ItemReader to get File Objects?

Tags: spring-batch

I think this should be a pretty regular use case but I'm pretty new to spring-batch and confused by some concepts.

I want to have a batch process that reads files from a directory (gets them as `File` Object). It also should be **partitioned**, and **restartable**.

Search yielded mainly examples for `FlatFileItemReader`, what I think is not what I need (I do not want to read them, just send them as File to a processor).

At the moment, my partitioner and reader look like this.

```
@Bean("partitioner")
@StepScope
public Partitioner partitioner() {
    MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner = new MultiResourcePartitioner();
    ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
    Resource[] resources = null;
    try {
        resources = resolver.getResources("classpath*:/*.json");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    partitioner.setResources(resources);
    partitioner.partition(10);
    return partitioner;
}

@Bean
@StepScope
@Qualifier("fileItemReader")
@DependsOn("partitioner")
public  ItemReader<File> fileItemReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}") String fileName){
    log.info("fileName from stepExecutionContext is " + fileName);

        return new ItemReader<File>() {
            //Reader has to return null, when he ended
            boolean fileHasBeenRead = false;

            @Override
            public File read() throws CustomRetryableException, FileNotFoundException {

                if (fileHasBeenRead == true){
                    log.info("has been read already");
                    return null;
                }
                else {
                    fileHasBeenRead = true;
                    return ResourceUtils.getFile(fileName);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I feel like this reader implementation is not really good and it also seems to be not restartable.

I have found another reader example, but do not know if it would work with partitioning [FileReader Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53854446/read-all-files-from-directory-spring-batch-filereadingmessagesource).

I've also stumbled across the `MultiResourceItemReader` , but I am not sure, if this could also be a solution.

What is the best way to use partitioning and ItemReader to get File objects to process, while also having restartability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Batch does not offer any `ItemReader` implementation that returns a `File` object so you are correct that you will need to implement your own.  With that, let's look at how Spring Batch makes its components restartable.

The main interface that enables restart-ability is the `ItemStream` interface.  This interface has three methods as shown below:

```
public interface ItemStream {

    void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException;

    void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException;

    void close() throws ItemStreamException;
}
```

The `open` method is used to establish the state of the component and initialize any components that need that (open files/etc).  This is also where the state of the component would be restored on a job's restart.  The state is retrieved from the `ExecutionContext` which is nothing more than a map of key/value pairs that was saved in previous executions.

The `update` method is where the component is given the opportunity to periodically save off its current state.  Things like number of records read, etc would be stored in the `ExecutionContext` which is later persisted to the job repository for later referencing on a restart (via the `open` method discussed above).

Finally the `close` method is used to release any unneeded resources and perform any final clean up (close files and database connections, etc).

When we consider the previous methods, a restartable component will implement the `ItemStream` interface so that the `update` method will save off any relevant state needed for a restart to the `ExecutionContext` and the open method will look for that state and if it exists, restore it (if there is no previous state it is not a restart).

With all of that in mind, we can now look at your specific use case of creating an `ItemReader` implementation that allows for returning a `File` object and is restartable.  In this case, you really have two things to determine:

1. **How to make the data set static -** In most restart cases with Spring Batch, it is assumed that the data set has not changed between runs.  In your case, the expectation is that the list of files has not changed from execution to execution.  If it has, the ability to make it restartable becomes more complex.  A good way to handle this is for each job instance, the files to be processed are tagged in some way (rename) or moved to a "processing" directory that is not changed from execution to execution.
2. **What state to store -** Once you have made the dataset static, Spring Batch can help you make it restartable.  I would extend the `AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader`.  This parent class will automatically count the number of items that have been returned and store them in the `ExecutionContext` for you.  This means that as you iterate over the array of `Resource` objects, the `AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader` would keep track of the index you are on.  So in your `open` method, you can get the array of resources *and sort it*.  From there, you have a consistent data set that all you need is the index to identify which items have been read and which ones have not.

Good luck and I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer and clarification on the restartability, but I feel like an important point is still left out, being the use of partitioner. In my provided code I use the MultiResourcePartitioner to partition for every file and then have a reader on @Stepscope just returning the File via getting the fileName out of executionContext. I tried both , writing a new Reader, extending AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader , which I think does not work, because it is not thread safe, and using my own code, but ItemStreamReader instead of ItemReader.

Comment: I think maybe I also confused the terms "restart" and "retry" for the reader. When reading in Files i wanted to be able to throw an exception and retry on this exception. I have found some links that say that it is only possible to skip exceptions from the Reader but not retry?! As my retry logic in the processors is working fine so far.

Comment: You are correct in that a reader is not retryable by Spring Batch (itself, you can obviously add retry semantics within your own `ItemReader` implementation).  The reason for this is that the reader's contract is "forward only".  There is no mechanism for Spring Batch to tell the `ItemReader` to go back to the previous element and try again.